# Installing Google recaptcha:2.0.0 on Magento Open Source 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, php, error, captcha, recaptcha

Included in [Magento documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/extension-install-google-recaptcha.html) the following steps to install Google recaptcha:2.0.0 on Magento Open Source 2.2.6:

Install Module:

```
 composer require msp/recaptcha:2.0.0
```

Enable Module:

```
php bin/magento module:enable --all

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

For the first code `composer require msp/recaptcha:2.0.0`, I get this error message:

```
 Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.2.5, required as 2.2.6) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.5] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: remove magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension 2.5.0
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.6].
    - Conclusion: don't install dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension 2.5.0
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.6 requires dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension 2.6.0 -> satisfiable by dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension[2.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension[2.5.0, 2.6.0].
    - Can only install one of: dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension[2.5.0, 2.6.0].
    - Installation request for dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension (locked at 2.5.0) -> satisfiable by dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension[2.5.0].
```

Any suggestions please about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to not add the 2.0.0, use without the version

> composer require msp/recaptcha

because that module is already upgraded

https://packagist.org/packages/msp/recaptcha is connected with this https://github.com/magento/magespecialist_ReCaptcha/releases . I think the 2.0.2 will be Upgraded .

```
composer require msp/recaptcha:2.0.2
```

Than check again if the error shows

Comment: I've try it without version but the same problem appear.